# How to handle several submit buttons in a form with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I need to create 30 buttons, from 1 to 30, whereby each one calls the exact same action script (e.g. all under the same form) where the parameter that is passed to the action script is simply the number of the button pressed (1 to 30).

For example, let's say the action script is process.php, if button 3 is pressed, then I need to pull data from process.php?btn=3, and if button 27 is pressed, then I need to pull data form process.php?btn=27.

What is the easiest, most straight-forward way of doing that with JQuery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it. The beforeSend function is just to show you what is being sent to the server.

```
$('button').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var number = $('form button').index(this);
    $.ajax('process.php', {
        data: 'number='+ number,
        beforeSend: function (jqHxR, settings) {
            alert(settings.data);
            return false;
        }
    });  
});
```

EDIT:
http://jsfiddle.net/EvilAmarant7x/NhMnP/

Comment: Could you please give me an example of the code I would use for an individual submit button for it to work with the code you wrote above?  Thanks.

Comment: @NeedExpertHelp I've updated my response. Let me know if you need a more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you give all of your links the class `.number`:

```
$("a.number").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = 'process.php?btn=' + $(this).text();
});

<a class="number" href="#">1</a>
<a class="number" href="#">2</a>
...
```

This seems to be the type of thing that is best done on the server side, as in having the server render each `href` with the correct param values. I am *assuming* that is not an option in your case.

EDIT: Asynchrony, as requested:

```
$("a.number").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // fill up div with ID="results" with content from server
    $("#results").load("process.php", { btn: $(this).text() }, function() {

        // callback to do something once the content has loaded
        // (perhaps not needed)

    });
});

<div id="results"></div>
...
<a class="number" href="#">1</a>
<a class="number" href="#">2</a>
...
```

See [`$.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Are you saying I should do this using <a> links (30 links) instead of as 30 submit buttons under a form?

Comment: You mentioned, "If you have 30 submit buttons you can assign each number as their values", which was actually what my original question was trying to get at, how exactly would I do that?  Also, what is advantage of doing this via links rather than via submit buttons?  Thanks again.

Comment: @NeedExpertHelp - scrap what I said in the last comment - you'll end up with all the buttons' names and values getting appended to the query string. The easiest way to go would be to have your links formed like this: `<a href="process.php?btn=1">1</a> <a href="process.php?btn=2">2</a>` and so on. No need for a form.

Comment: @karim79 - won't that load a new page rather than request the data asynchronously?

Comment: Heh, I thought that's what you wanted! No mention of asynchrony or ajax anywhere in your Q. I'll edit.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was implied when I mentioned JQuery in the title.  Thanks for the edit.  So would you recommend your solution over the solution by EvilAmarant7x ?  If so, what advantages does it have over it?  Thanks again!